# cant select same item from listbox after removal

Tags: wpf, listbox

I have a listbox and who's itemsource is bound to a List with SelectionMode="Single". My listbox also has an ItemContainerStyle set for it as below:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

When I remove an item from the list, I'm not able to reselect the item unless I select a different item and then go back to it. Can anyone give input on this?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are removing items from the list, the `ListView` might lose focus after the removal, which can affect the `Highlight Color` of the `SelectedItem`. The item is actually `Selected` but does not appear to be to the user because the `ListView` is not the active control. For example, this could happen if you click a button elsewhere on your form to delete an item from the `ListView`.

Try calling `Focus()` on your `ListView` instance after the remove operation.

Comment: how would I do that using MVVM?

Comment: Can you post some code as to how you are currently removing items from the list? I'll be able to help you more if I see your current implementation.